# I want to know principle of battletag(ex. battlenet, discord and so on)

Tags: php, mysql, security

Question: Can i expose `user_id(primary key of User table, auto increment)?`   px) email is unique

Goal: I want to allow duplication of nickname. So I will display `user_id` beside `nickname`. -> 'june#3208' like battletag of battlenet.

is it correct way? i worried about security.

Comment: Should be fine, why do you think it will be insecure?.. Your user id is 9584177 on stackoverflow, ill use that to login to your account :/

Comment: Battlenet and Discord do not expose the user ID like that. The four digit number you see behind nicknames changes when a user changes their nickname. It's just a random number that can be used to individually identify multiple users with the same nickname on the same server/channel.

Comment: thank you so much.than i have to store rand number in my User table, right? for checking duplicated battlecode?